# What is the usefulness of a separable space in topology, especially in terms of real-valued functions on the space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

There is a concept in topology called a separable space, which has a countable dense subset. If such a separable topological space also has an ordering (a binary relation like $\ge$), this concept of separability seems to be linked to the fact that the ordering can be represented by a real-valued function in the following sense (based on, e.g., Debreu 1954):

Let $A$ be the separable topological space equipped with a complete and transitive binary relation $\succsim$ and $u$ a real-valued function from $A$ to real numbers. Then, there is a function $u$ that represents $\succsim$ in the following sense:

$\forall a,b \in A, a \succsim b \Leftrightarrow u(a) \ge u(b)$

I have a few question in this regard:

1. Why does this existence of such a real-valued function derive from the definition of separable space?
2. Are separable spaces somehow linked to the set of real numbers (e.g. in terms of limitation of size)?
3. What other properties do separable spaces have?
4. What purpose have separable spaces been used in the past in topology?
5. The above existence result may depend on the topology used. Does it?

I might have also misunderstood something here, since I'm not an expert in topology. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Janne

Comment: I think we need more separability conditions, I'm not sure though. For example, does every point in the space have a neighborhood containing it? If not, I don't see how having a dense subset could help.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{N}$ with the following topology: 
$$\{\emptyset,\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z}\}$$
The closure of $\mathbb{N}$ is the smallest closed set containing it. Therefore, $\mathrm{Cl}{(\mathbb{N})}=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable dense set in $\mathbb{Z}$. 

How do you want to define a relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ based on this fact alone? And of course, $\mathbb{Z}$ has a complete, transitive binary relation on it. It's a totally ordered set.

Comment: The relation on $\mathbb{N}$ is normally just the normal $\ge$. The countable dense subset in this case would be $\mathbb{N}$ itself, so $\mathbb{N}$ is separable. In any case, we know from other results that such a representation $u$ exists for any countable set, and it wouldn't matter what sort of topology there is. Separability seems to start to play a bigger role for sets that are uncountable; sets with smaller cardinality are not that interesting here.

Comment: I wrote an answer. The answer was too big to be posted as a comment. I have assumed that each point has a neighborhood that contains it and created a function $\mu$ by taking a bijection between $Q$ and $\mathbb{N}$. Please check it and see if you think it's in the right direction or not. Meanwhile, my problem with your assumptions is that you do not have assumed the existence of a neighborhood for a point in the space. I do not see how you want to use the property of having a countable dense subset without having enough neighborhoods to approximate the points in the space. That's my issue.

Comment: Why would you add the [utility] tag back? Have you even read the description?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The description of the utility tag is ambiguous in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Take $Q$ to be a countable dense subset in $A$.

Since $Q$ is countable, there exists a bijective function $f: Q \to \mathbb{N}$.

Define an order on $Q$ by $a \geq_{\star} b \iff f(a)\geq f(b)$.

Now you have to be able to approximte an element in $A$ by elements in $Q$. This approximation has to be done by taking neighborhoods.

Assuming that each point has a neighborhood containing it, each $a \in A$ can be approximated by a $q \in Q$.

Since $A$ has a complete, transitive binary relation, either $q \geq a$ or $a \geq q$.

Do the same for $b$ and approximate it with $q'$ and you will get either $b \geq q'$ or $q' \geq b$

Now compare $q$ and $q'$ in $A$ and handle each possible case for these four numbers $a,b,q,q'$ separately. Consider each one of them separately and use transitivity. When transitivity is indecisive, define $u(a)=u(b)=\min\{f(q),f(q)\}$

Comment: This seems to make sense, but if you cannot do this approximation, i.e., if there is no such a countable dense set, then why does this imply that there is no such representation function? Is this somehow linked to the fact that real numbers have a countable dense set (the rationals) and that this ability to approximate is somehow necessary for the representation function to exist?

Comment: @JanneGustafsson I have no idea. But once you have a "countable dense" set, you get two things immediately: 1. A way to approximate the points of the space by a better understood set (the dense set), 2. An enumeration of that better understood set which gives us a function from the set to natural/rational numbers. Therefore, you get a function from your initial set to the real numbers by first approximating and then using the enumeration. "Maybe" a partial converse also holds which answers your comment, i.e. you can find a dense countable set from $u$ by considering the induced order topology.

Comment: Do you or somebody else in the forums know what purpose separable topological spaces are normally used? Maybe this holds a clue to the answer.